# How to get the missing paragraph between two `strip` environments

Tags: paragraphs

I tried `strip` environment for typing large matrix in a two column document. It works, but I felt some difficulty. When I used more than one `strip` environments frequently, I lost the paragraph  in between the two `strip` environments. Instead of the given paragraph, I am getting letter B in between the two `strips` as output.
Here I am enclosing the image of issue that I am facing.
[image]
Could you please assist me to fix the problem.
Here I am attaching the code I used

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{cuted}
\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]
     \begin{strip}
                \[
        K=\left[\begin{matrix}
            1+x^4+x^6 & x+x^4+x^6+x^7 & 1+x^3+x^7 & 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^5  \\
            1+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^7 & x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7 & x^3+x^5+x^7 & x^3+x^6  \\
            x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7 & 1+x^4+x^6 & 1+x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7 & x^4+x^5+x^7  \\
            x^3+x^5+x^6 & 1+x+x^2+x^7 & x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^7 & x+x^2+x^3+x^5+x^7\\
        \end{matrix} \right]
        \]
    \end{strip}
\lipsum[2]
% I lost the above \lipsum[2] while running the code
     \begin{strip}
        
        \[
        K=\left[\begin{matrix}
            1+x^4+x^6 & x+x^4+x^6+x^7 & 1+x^3+x^7 & 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^5  \\
            1+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^7 & x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7 & x^3+x^5+x^7 & x^3+x^6  \\
            x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7 & 1+x^4+x^6 & 1+x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7 & x^4+x^5+x^7  \\
            x^3+x^5+x^6 & 1+x+x^2+x^7 & x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^7 & x+x^2+x^3+x^5+x^7\\
        \end{matrix} \right]
        \]
    \end{strip}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, yet complete, code reproducing your problem.

Comment: I don't think that `cuted` supports more than one `strip` per page. Why not setting the two large equations in a `table*`?

Comment: @Bernard, Sir, I edited my question with the code I used.

Comment: @egreg, Sir, I tried it but while using the `table` code I am not getting the out put at the exact position where I need.

Comment: The idea is that you *reference* the table at the place you want.

Comment: @Bernard, Sir please help me to fix the problem